# Указатель на строку

Tags: c++, строки, указатели

Помогите, пожалуйста, как правильно присвоить указателю строку, чтобы не писало "невозможно преобразовать из string в char*"?

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>
 using namespace std;
 class Tree
{
string data;
char *top;
char*right;
char*left;

public:
Tree()
{
    getline(cin, data);
    top = data;
    right = NULL;
  left = NULL;
  }

int count();//количество ветвей

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно просто получить указатель на си-строку, то можно использовать функцию-член `c_str()` для `std::string`.

Если же нужно скопировать строковое представление из `std::string` в заранее выделенную память, то вызвать функцию копирования си-строк `strcpy`:

```
char s[100]; // следует выбрать достаточный размер для строки
std::string data; 
...
strcpy(s, data.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас неправильный подход к построению дерева.

Вам следует объявить структуру, которая будет описывать узел дерева, например, следующим образом

```
struct Node
{
    std::string data;
    Node *top;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};
```

и использовать эту структуру в построении дерева.

Вы можете эту структуру объявить внутри другой структуры, которая будет определять дерево. Например

```
class Tree
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        std::string data;
        Node *top;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
    } head;

public:
    Tree() : head( nullptr ) {}
    int count() const;//количество ветвей
};
```

И включить в эту структуры методы, которые будут манипулировать деревом: добавлять новые узлы, удалять, искать и т.д.

А то, что вы пытаетесь сделать, совершенно некорректно, не имеет смысла и не имеет отношение к построению дерева.